# Superslides CSS issue in Chrome - need CSS guru

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I have the superslides jQuery plugin installed here - http://coolon.businesscatalyst.com/
But the text container in Chrome only displays the text on the first slide. But works fine in FF and Safari.

Here is a link to the Superslides plugin in action with the text container working fine in Chrome - http://nicinabox.com/superslides/

I've tried everything and can't get it to display. Any thoughts!?

Comment: In chrome in developer tools text appers for slide after I change any css rule for `#fullslider ul.slides-container .static.container` css selector, but after slide changes bug appears again. Try to make some changes to that css selector each time slide changes or keep looking in that way to resolver your problem.

Comment: Yeah that is what I have been doing but nothing seems to work. I've set the display as relative and absolute, changed z-indexes etc but nothing works.

Comment: I see two errors.. `GET http://coolon.businesscatalyst.com/StyleSheets/ModuleStyleSheets.css 404 (ERROR: The file requested could not be found.)` and `http://coolon.businesscatalyst.com/img/loading.gif`

Comment: Having the same issue, and looking at your site which is fixed now: how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that your images have

```
webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Just remove it.

Comment: This does not fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue but than i replaced the jquery.superslides from the one i downloaded from http://archive.nicinabox.com/superslides/ and it got resolved. The bug has been fixed now in the updated version of it.